# HTTP insecure workaround for Firebase

Tags: https, firebase

As far as I know, Firebase does not allow any http endpoints, and Baidu Maps API does not have an https endpoint available. Any potential workarounds for getting Baidu Maps to work in a Firebase application?

I can't use Google Maps because this is a web-app for China. I think Bing Maps might be an option if I can't get Baidu Maps to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36069560/1342816

Basically is to add "&s=1" at the end of script src.