# Baidu map implementation on secure pages

Tags: security, dictionary, baidu

We are making our store locator pages secure for China site but the issue is Baidu URL 
https://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=1.4&ak=xxxxxx automatically redirect itself to http url.

When I hit above URL 'https://api.map.baidu.com/..' in browser it shows following code -

```
(function(){ window.BMap_loadScriptTime = (new Date).getTime();      
document.write('<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://api.map.baidu.com/getscript?
v=1.4&ak=xxxx&services=&t=20150522093217"></script>');})();
```

Using this URL directly 'http://api.map.baidu.com/getscript?v=1.4&ak=xxxx&services=&t=20150522093217' then it is accessible over https but then other issues start coming -

Blocked loading mixed active content "http://api.map.baidu.com/getmodules?v=1.4&mod=map,scommon,mapclick,oppc,navictrl,control"
 Blocked loading mixed active content "http://api.map.baidu.com/getmodules?v=1.4&mod=marker,tile"

Till now I found one blog  for this -
Source:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/mkN2-nuMSfY
mentioning that  there is separate API url to implement API over https something like- https://sapi.map.baidu.com/ but 
this solution not working and not able to find any documentation related to this on Baidu site.

If somebody has implemented Baidu over https please help on this.

Answer (score 4):

So basically Baidu map version 1.4 does not support secure URLs.So updated the code to include version 2.0

```
https://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=2.0&ak=xxxxxx&s=1
```

Other changes I have made

- Parameter 's=1' is  appended to the API url.
- Put Server IPs in white-listed Ips for the browser key
- All iframes, scripts and images urls must not start with http.

Comment: The `s` parameter is the necessary part to ensure that the script for `api.map.baidu.com/getscript` is requested securely.